# Google Analytics language suddenly changed to Polish

Tags: google-analytics, localization

I haven't configured my language to Polish in any of the Google's sites ever. I am not living near Poland. My account language is English. Even when I'm logged out, Google Analytics is Polish to me.

I wanted to change the language to English. I have tried other solutions but they were no good for me. It is funny that this exact tool is used to learn visitors language/region.

[image: I can't understand]

Comment: I wanted to change language to English. I have tried other solutions but they were no good for me... I deleted the cookies Google Analytics became "German" this time... :) But German is more familiar to me, so I could see the option at the bottom of the Google Analytics login page I fixed this issue and I can post it after 8 hours according to rules of stackexchange... Thanks.

Comment: Yes, please do post the solution. I'm sure you're not the only one who will run into this.

Comment: Ok. I have posted the solution now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution. Before logging in, there is a language selection at the bottom-right of the page.

[image: German this time...]

I couldn't find it because it was in Polish... Still can't understand why Google don't use general Google language settings on Google Analytics.